# Share WordPress Login Cookies Between Two Subdomain Installs

Tags: subdomains, cookies

I have two wordpress installs each on their own sub domain.

**sub1.domain.com** and **sub2.domain.com**

I want to share the login information between sub1 and sub2. I already have configured them to use the same MySQL database, and they use the same database table.

I am able to log in on both websites with the same credentials.

Sub2's wp-config.php file has the following code:

```
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'wp_c_users');

define('CUSTOM_USERMETA_TABLE', 'wp_c_usermeta');
```

This all works great. My problem, is that the cookies are not being shared between the sites. Instead of sharing the cookies both sites just delete the others and create a new cookie.

I added the following code to both sub1 and sub2's wp-config.php:

```
define('COOKIEPATH','domain.com/'); // Replace with your initial domain name
define('SITECOOKIEPATH','domain.com/'); // Replace with your initial domain name
define( 'COOKIEHASH',    md5( 'Y@^ET#UF!RG7#KQXP04^WF' ) );
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'domain.com');
```

When a user logs in to sub1, the cookie is created just fine, then when I go to sub2.domain.com, I am not also logged in on this site.

When I then try to log in to sub2.domain.com, it deletes sub1's cookies and overwrites them.

How can I get these two wordpress installations to use the same cookie instead of overwriting eachothers??

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I even setup an a new subdomain called Test and tried to share cookies between the main domain and the new sub domain but it didn't work. I am guessing this method no longer works with WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Today, I've posted a working solution for exactly the same problem. You can see it here: [How to share WordPress session and cookies between domain and subdomain?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130753/how-to-share-wordpress-session-and-cookies-between-domain-and-subdomain/264490#264490). I use this method on several of my own websites.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to add a leading dot in the `COOKIE_DOMAIN` and just leave the `COOKIEPATH` and `SITECOOKIEPATH` undefined.

So the constants would be

```
define( 'COOKIEHASH', md5( 'Y@^ET#UF!RG7#KQXP04^WF' ) );
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.domain.com' );
```