# Single sign on to sub-sites in Multisite Network

Tags: multisite, login, subdomains, cookies, https

I have a Multisite Network setup which consists in a primary site under **https://** and many sub-sites under **http://**

Supposedly, WordPress should automatically handle the cookies so that when a user logs in from the primary site, the same user should be automatically logged in to every other sub-site belonging to him.

However, this is not the case for me, I am guessing that when the user logs in from the primary site the cookies are being set for **https://** and not shared with the other **http://** sub-sites?

So, how can I allow users to automatically be logged in to all their sub-sites (**http://**) when logging in from the primary site (**https://**) ?

Am I missing something? Is there a way to maybe share cookies from https to http? Would that fix the issue?

Comment: Is your Multisite installation a subdomain one? (The tags on your question would seem to indicate that it is.)

Comment: yes it is, sorry I missed that information

Comment: This might help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130753/how-to-share-wordpress-session-and-cookies-between-domain-and-subdomain/264490#264490