# Enable Wordpress to share cookies between domain.com and sub.domain.com

Tags: cookies

I have a Wordpress core install on domain.com and am building a JavaScript web application, without Wordpress, on sub.domain.com. I'd like to see whether or not the user has logged into domain.com, to determine whether or not to show a custom admin bar on sub.domain.com.

I see a cookie that is set when I log into domain.com (e.g., wordpress_logged_in_abcde12345).

How can I send a "set-cookie" header for specific subdomains in the API response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share WordPress session and cookies between domain and subdomain?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130753/how-to-share-wordpress-session-and-cookies-between-domain-and-subdomain)

Comment: @JacobPeattie in his case he is dealing with two Wordpress core installs, with PHP. He is able to set env variables in both. In my case, I am trying to communicate between a WP core install and a JavaScript web application.