# Why is my staging subdomain not sending wordpress_logged_in cookies?

Tags: plugins, login, cookies, staging, clone-site

We have a custom login and account creation plugin. It works fine on our live environment `(example.com)` but not on our staging environment `(test.example.com)`.

When we call `wp_insert_user` via an AJAX function, it successfully creates the user and returns their ID. `wp_signon` also appears to work. But in both cases, the user doesn't actually get logged in on the staging environment.

After looking through Chrome's developer tools, I realized that the live environment is sending `set-cookie: wordpress_logged_in_...` like it's supposed to, but the staging environment is not.

There's nothing in the error log about this, and it happens if we disable all of our other plugins on the staging environment.

What could be the cause of this? How can we make it send the login cookies like it's supposed to?

Comment: do you have any login mechanism on your staging env, to hide it from public? are URL path's in database correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the staging environment had different content in its wp-config.php and .htaccess files. I changed them to be closer to the ones on the live environment.

While I was there, I noticed that some of the differing content was related to various caching plugins that we previously had installed on the staging environment. In desperation, **I reinstalled all of those plugins through wp-admin and then uninstalled them**.

Surprisingly, that fixed the issue of the cookies not being sent. However, the cookies had incorrect paths or domains. After some trial and error, I finally got it working by **adding these seven lines to wp-config.php**:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/wp-admin');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'test.example.com');
define('WP_HOME','https://test.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://test.example.com');
```

My assumption is that one or more of the caching plugins hadn't cleaned up after itself when we uninstalled it.

Comment: Another reason why Nginx is so much easier to work with... no `.htaccess` to worry about and server-level caching (no cache plugins/hacks). Also if you want more verbose settings you can use `.example.com` for `COOKIE_DOMAIN` here (the default/blank value is doing the same thing). See also: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130753/how-to-share-cookies-and-sessions-between-domain-and-subdomain/264490#264490

Comment: Also the `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` is only for Multisite installations.