# Authenticate Subdomain

Tags: authentication

I have a sub-domain which I'm trying to restrict to authenticated Wordpress users but the authentication isn't working.
I've tried the following code:

```
global $current_user; 
wp_get_current_user(); 
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n"; 
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n"; 
    } else { 
    wp_loginout(); 
    }
```

This works if I use the URL domain.com/intranet/page.php but not on intranet.domain.com/page.php
How can I get it to work for subdomains?
I've tried adding the following to wp-config.php but that hasn't done anything:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.domain.com'); // Used to authenticate subdomains
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is this a multisite? Or two separate installs? Or one install that is not a multisite? If it does not work, how is it broken? Are you bootstrapping WordPress into standalone PHP files? It's highly unusual to directly visit a PHP file that didn't come from WordPress itself

Comment: It's standalone PHP files outside of wordpress. Trying to integrate existing web apps using the Wordpress authantication rather than 2 sets of user data. I know it's slightly unusual, but this is the requirement I'm faced with.

Comment: you'll need to provide more information about where WordPress is located, if it's a multisite or a single site, etc, there's not enough information here to make a recommendation or write an answer, and you only answered the last question I asked and ignored the first 4 questions. If you do not know the answers please say so

Comment: Sorry Tom - I thought it was clear from my response, but my mistake. The WP is a single site in the parent public_html dir (domain.com) and the web app is in a sub-domain (intranet.domain.com) which is just a pointer to a sub-directory (domain.com/intranet). So calling it in the sub-directory works, but when I call it using the subdomain URL it doesn't.
When I say it doesn't work, I mean that the username is displayed as expected using the full URL but not when I use the subdomain URL.

Comment: And the expected cookie is there on the full URL but not on the subdomain URL.

Comment: hmm so your cookie sessions don't show up on the subdomain, but if they did then your code would pick them up and recognise the user, I see! And `/intranet` and `intranet.domain.com` are both served by the same application. This makes things much clearer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that `COOKIEHASH` has the same value for both, e.g.:

```php
define( 'COOKIEHASH', md5( 'https://yourdomain.com' ) );
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.yourdomain.com' );
```

See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/264490/736

Comment: Took me ages to get this working until I realised the code needs to be before `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`

Comment: This has been working fine for me and I've just migrated to a new VPS and getting this: Warning: Constant COOKIEHASH already defined in /
Any suggestions why?

Comment: none, maybe best as a new question but I'd put the entire error message in when you ask it, and I'd also do a search for `COOKIEHASH` across the files to find the other define statement if it's not in that file

Comment: Not sure why I wasn't seeing the errors before, but seems like I didn't need it in the sub-domain header so removed and now working.